# Get items from a list using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Linq

Tags: list, linq

I am trying to get the items from a Sharepoint list with no luck. My code resembles the following:

```
  using (DataContext data = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
  {
       var typeList= data.GetList<MyType>("SomeList");

       var ty = from t in typeList
                orderby t.SortOrder
                select t;

        //this causes the exception
        var aList = ty.ToList();
  }
```

Whenever I try to iterate over the items in a loop, or call ToList() on the result of the query, I get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

I'm at a loss. In .Net, I can go things like this:

```
var something = myList.OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder).ToList();
```

How do I do something similar in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
using (DataContext data = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
   var typeList= data.GetList<SPListItem>("SomeList");

   List<SPListItem> ty = (from SPListItem tin in typeList.Items
                orderby tin.Id
                select tin).ToList();

    foreach (var oItem in ty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oItem.Title);
    }
}
```

[How to work with SharePoint Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538250(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Nope. I still get the same exception on the ToList() call. I've been to the MSDN examples.

Comment: I did a small change instead of MyType I used SPListItem. And I believe "SomeList" is your list title. Can you try this change

Comment: That won't work because SPListItem doesn't have a SortOrder property.

Comment: Can you use ID in that place? like `orderby tin.ID`

Comment: I can remove the orderby completely and still get the same exception.